# Hibernate Criteria - Group By

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have own table containing car data:

- EntryID
- CarID
- CustomerID
- CarAge

What I do want is to get newest car of every customer. Using a common query, I would order the data by date DESC and then group by customer.

Using criteria, I tried this:

```
session.createCriteria(Car.class)
    .addOrder(Order.desc("CarAge"))
    .setProjection( Projections.groupProperty("CustomerID"));
```

Strangely, this does not return Car objects but it returns a list of customer IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect Car objects.

```
select * from Car group by customerId order by carAge desc;
```

The above sqlquery does not work in database as well. Below is the query that is executed by Hibernate.

```
select customerId from Car group by customerId order by carAge desc;
```

If you need other columns as well, add it as group property and you will get it, else get all the ids and query the database again to get rest of the values else write HQL to have subquery to return specific customer ids

Comment: is it better that we use hql or get id with criteria and then get each object separately?